# About ActionScript3 and encoding characters

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3, encoding, utf-8, ucs2

I have a flash app and a textfield in it. I can change locale on the system tray and type unicode chracters, for example with windows -1251 encoding. If I use jquery to send the unicoded text to save to database, how does it get there, as windows-1251 encoded or other encoding, like UTF-8?

Or lets just say with which encoding it get to jquery at first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All strings have UTF8 encoding, so if you get text of textfield it'll have UTF8 encoding